# Using CameraCaptureTask to launch the default camera app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

*Windows Phone 8* gives the ability to change the default camera app with another one downloaded from the store, making this new app the one that's launched when you hit the camera hardware button.

So I was wondering if is there any chance to launch this app using the `CameraCaptureTask`.

What I'd like to do is something simple like

```
var camera = new CameraCaptureTask();
camera.Show();
camera.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(camera_Completed);
```

but I want this to work with the default app that the user chose on its device, and not with the basic Microsoft's one.

I've not found anything online, so I'm asking to you guys if I can make what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, not possible with the current API.